# CGI::escapeHTML is escaping single quote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently upgraded my Ruby 1.9.3 to 2.0.0 and had a surprise ; CGI::escapeHTML is now escaping single quote, meaning:

```
CGI::escapeHTML("'")
=> "&#39;"
```

The wierdest thing is that, when going to definition of escapeHTML, everything seems fine, and copying the definition of the method give the right result (it doesn't escape single quote)

Does anyone have a clue about this?

Thanks,

Comment: Quotes are escaped in case they are included in attribute values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, it does what is defined in the 2.0 source. But you are right, the implementation changed from 1.9.3 to 2.0.

[1.9.3 source:](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escapeHTML)

```
def CGI::escapeHTML(string)
  string.gsub(/[&\"<>]/, TABLE_FOR_ESCAPE_HTML__)
end
```

[2.0 source:](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escapeHTML)

```
def CGI::escapeHTML(string)
  string.gsub(/['&\"<>]/, TABLE_FOR_ESCAPE_HTML__)
end
```

**Why have they changed it?**

It was done in [this commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/c47cca2f858f2665a6424e417745a9fd7e78003c) because (according to [bug #5485](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5485)) the [OWASP recommends](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Element_Content) to escape single quotes before inserting them in to HTML. So it's a security thing.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want the new behaviour. That I was using CGI::Escape is perhaps wrong, but I had no time to figure out why or rework it. I just wanted the old behaviour back.

I ended up taking the ' character out while I call CGI::Escape:

```
 def escapeHTML(title)
  char = "\u00A9"
  target_title = title.gsub("'", char)
  target_title = CGI.escapeHTML(target_title)
  target_title = target_title.gsub(char, "'")
  return target_title
 end
```

Find a char you know won't appear in your input!